# Sharepoint retrieving username without domain or programmatically removing domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm returning the username from sharepoint site as a string. This is done successfully with the below code but I also get the domain with it. How can I only return the username and not the domain either through sharepoint or programmatically removing it? domain/username

```
 private string CurrentUserName()
    {
        string userName = "NA";
        SPContext currentContext;
        try
        {
            //Getting the current context
            currentContext = SPContext.Current;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            currentContext = null;
        }
        if (currentContext != null && currentContext.Web.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            userName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return userName;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the user is returned in this format

```
domain\username
```

you can do the following:

```
string userWithoutDomain = userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

If the format is like this

```
username@domain
```

then the following will work

```
string userWithoutDomain = user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf('@'));
```

Probably you should test which format you have and extract the user name based on that. If the user name contains neither a @ nor a \ then you just return the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Change name column in user information list.and u get SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name
because login name can not change.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below code

```
 site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
             web = site.OpenWeb();
            userName = web.CurrentUser.Name.ToString() ;
```

Comment: user.name is not this same as loginName my name can be "Users First" and login "oc\user01" i assume he wants "user01"

Comment: That does not answer his question at all and it is the wrong answer.